# Can't make Delete to work on C++

Tags: c++, destructor, delete-operator

I'm trying to destroy objects in C++, but I can't make it to work. I have a few questions about how to clear memory in C++, something that I didn't have to do in Java because of GarbageCollector.

I have the following destructor and attributes for my Image class:

```
Class Image{
public:
Image(int w, int h){
    width = w; height = h;
    pixels = new int[w*h];
}
    ~Image() {
        delete [] pixels;
}
private:

        int *pixels; 
        int width, height;

}
```

This is what i'm doing with my Images:

```
void keyboard(unsigned char key, int x, int y){
        Image* sub1 = new Image(1,1);
        Image* sub2 = new Image(1,1);
    if (key == 'd' && camadas[1].getpXf() < camadas[1].getImage().getWidth() - gameWidth/2) {

        sub1 = &camadas[0].ScrollH(true);
        sub2 = &camadas[1].ScrollH(true);
        sub1->plot(sub2->getPixels(), 0, 0, gameWidth, gameHeight);
        lastScreen = sub1->getPixels();
        glutPostRedisplay();
    }
    if (key == 'a' && camadas[1].getpXi() > 0) {

        sub1 = &camadas[0].ScrollH(false);
        sub2 = &camadas[1].ScrollH(false);
        sub1->plot(sub2->getPixels(), 0, 0, gameWidth, gameHeight);
        lastScreen = sub1->getPixels();
        glutPostRedisplay();

    }
    delete sub1
    delete sub2;

}
```

My questions are:

1. Why are my commands "delete" not working? What I need to do to make them work? The "delete" don't get highlighted on Visual Studio 2015, and when the codes get to it the Visual Studio stops my program and says that "There is a Breakpoint".
2. Is there a better way to control the memory my program is using? I am using too much memory because every time I press "a" or "d" I capture another photo of an Image, and I get lots of memory use because I'm not deleting these Images from the memory.

There are more stuff on the class Image and there is even 1 more class (Layer), but for my question I don't think they will help.

Comment: There is at least on } missing at the destructor. Which of the deletes does not work? The one in the constructor or the other two?

Comment: Your code can not be compiled, I see at least two errors with this. When you say your 'delete command doesn't work', what exactly do you mean, ah?

Comment: Why not use one of the standard templates

Comment: You don't bother checking "new Image" for success? If you want it to be auto managed you could use `auto im1 = std::unique_ptr<Image>(1,1);` instead (if you're using c++11) to have it auto managed instead of using a delete. But if you only need it locally here, you can use the stack instead, just do `Image im1(1,1);` instead of allocating it on the heap.

Comment: Also the delete within the Image class is a bit problematic - `pixels` is an array, right (Could you please add the allocation code for this?) - How is the compiler to know how big the array is?

Comment: Please distinct "don't compile" and "don't work"

Comment: Although it will be less educational, so that you probably only should do it once you understand what went wrong here, you could use `std::array<int, ???> pixels` or `std::vector<int> pixels` instead of the `int * pixels` there, this way it'd be also handled, without you needing to explicitly write the delete in the d'tor

Comment: (I suggested using the stack instead of the heap, but if it's a really large object you might still be better with unique_ptr, after all. Of course if it's a large object you might want to keep it allocated and modify it instead of allocating/ de-allocating all the time, you know, the usual considerations)

Comment: @SergeyA the code was compiling. There is a lot more in the code and i dnd't want to cover it all. Maybe i deleted something important by mistake.

Comment: @EdHeal What Standard templates?

Comment: @Guest 86 Added how the array is being allocated. Gonna try using the unique_ptr

Comment: Std::vector perhaps. Google it

Comment: @RafaelCopat, here's a couple of examples of using this stuff, https://ideone.com/9vdQ0w

Answer (score 6):

You are creating two pointers

```
Image* sub1 = new Image(1,1);
Image* sub2 = new Image(1,1);
```

Then you reassign them in your if statement

```
sub1 = &camadas[0].ScrollH(true);
sub2 = &camadas[1].ScrollH(true);
```

This leaks the memory that `sub1` and `sub2` pointed to as they no longer point to it so it is unrecoverable.  Then when you call

```
delete sub1
delete sub2;
```

you are trying to delete

```
camadas[0].ScrollH(true);
camadas[1].ScrollH(true);
```

Which is [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

You also are not showing a constructor for `Images`.  If `pixels` is not being declared with `new[]` then you destructor is also wrong as you only call `delete` on something that you called `new` on and you only use `delete[]` when you used `new[]`